# Reference id into array and map it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have such an array.

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "one",
    cats: [],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "two",
    cats: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "sub 1",
    cats: [],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "sub 2",
    cats: [],
  },
];
```

How can i correctly reference the id 3 and 4 to the nested array of cats.

I need to achive the following.

I need to display the list as buttons, but the ones that have nested to be dropdown.

example

```
one.title
two.title
  sub1.title
  sub2.title
```

I dont want to have id 3 and 4 data like title, into the nested array because the router takes ID as param, so basically when i will click on sub1 it should display data from id-3.

Please help me understand this as i am new.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to fomat your array:

```
  const formatArray = arr =>
    arr.map(item => {
      if (item.cats.length === 0) {
        return item;
      } else {
        const itemtFormatted = { ...item };
        itemtFormatted.cats = item.cats.map(cat =>
          arr.find(e => e.id === cat.id)
        );
        return itemtFormatted;
      }
    });
```

You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/x9o6dkum/